# In iTunes Store, how can you view the full name?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store, itunes-u

When I'm looking in the store (iTunes U, specifically), many of the titles are cut off, ending in "..."  I thought the standard "hold the cursor over the text" would show a little window with the whole name, but no.  The only workaround I found was making the iTunes window wider.  Any way to make the column wider, or otherwise show the whole name?  (There's no way to change the column width by dragging at the top, like you would in your iTunes library).[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press the small 'i' button to the right of the description column, the information is shown again, in a pop-over box.  This does seem to show the full name.

[image: iTunes U pop-over box]

Comment: If you upload the screenshot to another image hosting company then upload it here, ping me "@bassplayer7" or flag it and someone should edit it in.

Comment: Thanks @bassplayer7, much appreciated -- looks like I have the reputation to sort this out myself now, though :)